# Tweak.xm not working

Tags: deb, jailbreak

I used Flex to get the info I needed and used Flex to test the tweak so I know its the correct info and it works. As many of you know you cannot use Flex to distribute your tweak so you must create a debian package for Cydia. In my `Tweak.xm` I have this code:

```
%hook FBUserPreferences

-(BOOL) isEmployee
{
return TRUE;
}

%end
```

This is meant to be a tweak to allow Facebook internal settings, also known as employee settings, but when installed it does not work. Please help, what did I do wrong in the `Tweak.xm`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you taking a look at the following classes, besides `FBUserPreferences`, as there are employee variables aswell:

```
FBLoggedOutExperimentManagerPolicy
FBSessionExperimentManagerPolicy
FBBugReportShakeHandler
FBBugReportInitialCoordinator
FBBugReportContainerViewController
FBBugReportChooseFeatureViewController
FBExceptionHandler
```

Hook the above classes and change the employee variables in there (just search for "Employee" in Flex, you'll come up with all of the above classes) as well.

Also, variable types are not written uppercase in Objective C. So, your `BOOL` must me `bool`:

```
%hook FBUserPreferences
-(bool) isEmployee {return TRUE;}
%end
```

Do this for every of the above variables and your tweak will work.